# Searching 2 Attributes at the same time CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, predicate

I'm trying to use a predicate to search 2 attributes at the same time. I initially tried a compound predicate but it would only return results if both predicates matched the string.

Basically I'm looking for something similar to this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[cd] %@" || "plainTextBody CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString, searchString)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I apply multiple predicates to an NSFetchRequest? Would it be better to manually parse my results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129508/can-i-apply-multiple-predicates-to-an-nsfetchrequest-would-it-be-better-to-manu)

Comment: Thanks @pawello2222 - I literally just figured out the answer, I was close enough in the first place and a slight tweak returned the results I was expecting. I posted the answer below just in case anyone else comes across this.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems I was close with my original post but it's important to keep the search terms in quotation marks and not separate them like I did in my original question. Simply using the following works perfectly:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[cd] %@ || plainTextBody CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString, searchString)
```